# After changing the configuration, the second monitor stopped working

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have two monitors. The main monitor is FullHD, works via HDMI. The second HD monitor works through the VGA. Connection diagram: The main monitor is connected to the HDMI video card, the Second monitor is connected to the VGA motherboard.

Previously there was a GTX 650, and an I3-3210 - everything worked. Now I installed GTX 1660 and I5-2400 - both monitors do not want to work at the same time.
If I set the BIOS priority to the integrated graphics, the second monitor works, the main one does not. If I do the opposite, the first monitor works, the second does not.

Replacing with an old CPU did not help. The new video card does not have a VGA output. I heard that both video cards (built-in Intel Graphics 2500 and GTX 1660) cannot work at the same time. What could be the problem?

Note: I did nothing to the system when replacing hardware, only installing a new driver for the video card. OC Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's usually a reason why only one is working, and in your case it sounds like it is because you have a video card **and** want to use the integrated graphics. Some CPUs/Motherboards only let you use one. A GTX 1660 should have more than 1 video port. Connect both monitors to either thr 1660 or to the MB (if one only supports VGA, you can get a really cheap adapter on Amazon)

Comment: My old video card (GTX 650) had an HDMI output and a VGA output. I specifically connected the second monitor to the motherboard so as not to load it. But only the video card worked. The new video card does not have a VGA output, and it cannot work with a monitor through the motherboard. Is it like this? If that's the only problem, there's no point in asking how to change it. There are many questions on the Internet about how to use two video cards in parallel. But I was sure until the last moment that this was not the problem.

Comment: It could be that your system cannot run two video cards simultaneously, but if it can, go into the BIOS and see if there is an option to turn on the Core i5's integrated graphics. There should be a 'configuration' tab somewhere. (If not, use the HDMI on the 1660, and get a DVI-D to VGA cable for the other monitor. Don't worry about putting too much load on the 1660, it's a relatively strong card and will work fine!)